# Should I create more database for different client - Meteor?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, meteor, websocket

I am using Metoer and mysql to build my web app. I may have multiple clients. Every client has most of the same logic. They have the same data structure, but some of the table will be huge. 
Different client is totaly separate.

I just wondering if I can create different database for client separately(every database has the same tables, but I don't have to fetch the data by join different client.), or just one database? I don't konw which way is better.

I think it is good for data management by using separate database. But I am worrying the performance.

If I just use one database for multiple client. Some of the tables will be extremely huge. Also will affect the performace.

Any ideas?

Comment: "_Some of the tables will be extremely huge_": how many records? Databases are designed to be big. Performance can be improved in a few ways, mainly careful indexing. I would be more worried about risk of making a mistake and mixing data of different clients. To be balanced with the hassle of having to handle several databases.

Comment: Every client may have over fifty million records per year.

Comment: 50m/y/client should still be on the low side.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends mainly on the resources of your DB server. Most importantly RAM. There are a few configuration settings you can tweak to improve performance and of course there are performance monitoring applications that may help. Personally, I wouldn't create a new db for each client. I'd probably choose InnoDB with the innodb_file_per_table option on to store each table in its own file. Beyond that I'd rely upon the monitoring software to make recommendations to improve efficiency.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table

For performance monitoring check out Cluster Control. They offer a free edition.

https://severalnines.com/product/clustercontrol/performance-management

Comment: Thanks for replay. I will have a try.

Comment: Another option is to set up a separate server for each client. This gives you a guarantee of isolation between clients, but may not be ideal if you have many clients. Or you could put larger clients on their own server?

Answer (score 0):

The physical size of a table or database doesn't really matter as long as the tables are correctly indexed. In case of a lack of performance, you may consider sharding. The main reason why you could choose the one database per user approach is security. Indeed, if every user access his own database, there are no risks of accidentally exposing other users data. From an organizational perspective, I would advise you to go with the one database for all users approach.